Software Update failing after change of certificate
I have taken over development of a piece of code. It's written in Visual Basic, and the manifest is signed. The original certificate has expired and is no longer available as the person who set it up has left the company.
I have rebuilt the application with the new certificate and try to update, but our application throws an exception:

"User has refused to grant required permissions to this application."

I didn't as far as I know refuse anything.
The details are as follows:
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException: User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate(Boolean persistUpdateCheckResult)
   at HighlandDataPlus.Form1.InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo()
   at HighlandDataPlus.Form1.UpdateApplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

This seems to be related to the new code signing certificate as switching back to the old build removes the trust issues. As far as I know the new version does not require any permissions the old version didn't have.
This happens however the "current" installed version's manifest is signed.
A similar question was posted in 2016 but c# based: C# ClickOnce Application - User has refused to grant required permissions to the application

To add some info the MSDN page on trust not granted exception states:
The application uses Trusted Application Deployment and the digital certificate used to sign the application is not listed as a trusted publisher on the local machine. If you have deployed an update to an application, and the update uses more permissions than the previous version, and ClickOnce throws a TrustNotGrantedException, the new version will not install.
This suggests that the new certificate is not trusted for some reason. But it does not demonstrate how to get it registered.
